# Paste append multiple lines

Tags: multiple-lines, paste

I search a way to paste/merge 2 block of text

```
apple
pear
banana

tomato
beans
potato
```

like this

```
apple tomato
pear beans
banana potato
```

The lines have different length but same number of lines of course.
I don't want different number of spaces like in visual block paste, and I search a way without using macro.

It's something we can easily do in sublime text, but I can't find an easy way to do it in vim.

Thx

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but try using visual block mode (`<C-v>`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be very easy with a macro, but you've stated don't want to use one, so here's a few alternative methods. I think they're all more complicated than a simple macro-based solution, but they show off some interesting features of Vim that readers might want to use in other scenarios.

### Using [`:normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) edits

```
:5,7norm!d$4kA ^R"

 5,7                # On lines 5 through 7
    norm!           # run normal mode commands that
         d$         # delete to the end of the line,
           4k       # move up 4 lines,
             A      # append a space, and
               ^R   # insert the contents of (note that this is a literal CTRL-R:
                    #                         to insert it type <C-V><C-R>
                 "  # the unnamed register   (i.e. the text we deleted)
```

### Using [`:move`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Amove) and [`:join`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Ajoin)

```
:5m.|-1j|+1

 5m.         # Move line 5 below this line
    |        # and then
     -1j     # join the two lines
        |    # and then
         +1  # move down a line
```

This will append the 5th line to the current line. You can then repeat it twice to complete the edits by typing:

```
2@:
```

*(Thanks to [D. Ben Knoble in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22827/paste-append-multiple-lines/22831?noredirect=1#comment41388_22831) for the suggestion to use `:join`.*)

You could also perform the join with the normal mode command `J`:

```
:5m.|norm!kJj

 5m.           # Move line 5 below this line
    |          # and then
     norm!     # run normal mode commands that
          k    # move up a line,
           J   # join the line below, and
            j  # move down a line
```

### Using [`:substitute`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As)

```
:1,3s/$/\= ' '.getline(line('.') + 4)

 1,3                                   # On lines 1 through 3
    s/                                 # substitute
      $                                # the end of the line
       /                               # with
        \=                             # the result of the expression
           ' '                         # a space
              .                        # followed by
               getline(             )  # the contents of the line
                       line('.') + 4   # four lines below this one.
```

This leaves the original second block of lines in place. You can then remove them with the command:

```
:4,7d
```

Comment: Will `:join` not work for the move variant?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes! Much nicer.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to suggest using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (`<C-v>`) to make a block.

It sounds as if putting the second block after the first doesn't do what you want.  However, if you put the *first* block in front of the second block, it should work.

To move the first paragraph to before the second paragraph you can do:

```
vip<C-v>$x"_d)P

vip              # Visually select the first [Inner] Paragraph (cursor inside first block)
   <C-v>$        # Change to Visual Block mode and select all the way to end of line
         x       # Cut the first paragraph into default register
          "_d)   # Delete paragraph into black hole register to remove leftover empty lines
              P  # Prepend the first paragraph (line-wise) before second paragraph
```

However, that doesn't leave any space between items. For example:

```
apple

tomato
```

turns into

```
appletomato
```

One way to fix this is to append a space to every item in the first block

```
vip:s/$/ <enter>

vip              # select the first paragraph
   :             # enter command mode
    s            # substitute command
     /$          # replace End of line...
       / /       # with a space (the second '/' here is optional)
         <enter> # press enter to complete the substitution command
```

#### Altogether:

```
vip:s/$/ <enter>vip<C-v>$x"_d)P
```

---

Original answer: (similar in idea to above solution, but not as generic). See more explanations in an [earlier revision](https://vi.stackexchange.com/revisions/22829/1).

```
Vjj:s/$/ /<enter>C^v2k$x4jPgg4dd
^---------------^       ^^ ^---^
Put a space @ end       *1    *3
                 ^-----^  ^
                 Cut top  2
*1 - Go down
*2 - Paste
*3 - Cleanup
```

---

#### Freebee alternative

A completely different solution that *would* require macros because it only does the move one line at a time. It jumps between top and bottom blocks and combines them.

One iteration is:

```
)jD<C-o>pkJj

)j           # Move down to the second paragraph and onto first line
  D          # Delete the top line of the second paragraph
   <C-o>     # Jump back to the top paragraph (Ctrl+o)
        pk   # Put line from bottom below and move back to top line
          J  # Join the two lines (white space is taken care of, leaves a single space)
           j # Move down a line, ready to do it again
```

This moves

```
     Run once:           Repeat            Repeat
apple    =>  apple tomato  =>  apple tomato  =>  apple tomato
pear         pear              pear beans        pear beans
banana       banana            banana            banana potato

tomato       beans             potato
beans        potato
potato
```

To create and use this as a macro do `qt)jD<C-o>pkJjq` and `2@t`. (create and use a macro in register `t`)

Comment: I wrote my set of answers essentially for fun, but this seems like it's the correct answer, given (or indeed ignoring!) the constraints.